# "Cannot bind parameter because Param2 is specified more than once"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to call a PS script via batch file, like so

```
Powershell.exe -file "C:\Scripts\Blah\Blah\Blah.ps1" -webUID "usernameValue" -webPWD "passwordValue" -Param "param value" -Param2 "param 2 value"
```

The issue seems to be the batch file is confusing Param and Param2. It thinks I am setting Param2 *twice* however Param and Param2 are separate parameters altogether. Has anyone experienced this? Is there perhaps a way to explicitly state the param names? Thanks

Param block

```
# Parameters
Param
(
  [string]$WebUID,
  [string]$WebPWD,
  [string]$Param,
  [string]$Param2
)
```

Comment: Is it perhaps specified more than once in the parameter _definition_? Can you show us your code, or at least the `param()` block?

Comment: I added to OP. Each parameter is only specified once. However when I remove Param from batch call, it works. Which is why im thinking its reading the parameters as wildcard values and confusing Param with Param2

Comment: If you add `[CmdletBinding()]` before the `Param()` block, does it change it anything?

Comment: Same error message :/

Comment: I can't reproduce it here using the posted code. There must be something in the batch file that messes the params up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an effort to support concise command-line use, PowerShell's "elastic syntax" allows specifying *unambiguous prefix substrings* of parameter names so that you only need to type as much of a parameter name as is necessary to identify it without ambiguity;
e.g., typing `-p` to refer to `-Path` is enough, if no other parameters start with `p`.

However, an *exact* match is always recognized, so that specifying `-Param` in your case *should* unambiguously match the `-Param` parameter, even though its full name happens to be a prefix substring of different parameter `-Param2`.

**If the problem *were* an issue of ambiguity (it isn't), you'd see a *different* error message.** For instance, were you to use the ambiguous `-Para`, you'd see:
`Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'para' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Param -Param2.`

Instead, **the wording of *your* error message suggests that the exact same parameter name - `-Param2` - was indeed specified *more than once*** - even though your sample code doesn't show that.

<sup>I've tested the behavior in PSv2 and PSv5.1 / 6.0 alpha 10 - it's conceivable, however, that other versions act differently due to a bug. Do let us know.</sup>

---

Consider an **alternative approach**:

*If* you invoked your script from *within PowerShell*, you could use a single, *array-valued* parameter - e.g. `[string[]] $Params` - and then simply pass as many parameters as needed, *comma-separated*, without needing to specify a distinct parameter name for each value.

Sadly, when invoking a script from *outside of PowerShell*, this approach won't work, because passing arrays isn't supported from the outside.

There is a *workaround*, however:

- **Declare the array-valued parameter decorated with `[parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]`**
- Invoke the script with the parameters as a *space-separated list at the end* of the command.

Applied to your scenario:

If your script defined its parameters as follows:

```
Param
(
  [string]$WebUID,
  [string]$WebPWD,
  [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
  [string[]] $Params
)
```

You could then invoke your script as follows:

```
Powershell.exe -file "C:\Scripts\Blah\Blah\Blah.ps1" `
  -webUID "usernameValue" `
  -webPWD "passwordValue" `
  "param value" "param 2 value"
```

and `$Params` would receive an *array* of values: `$Params[0]` would receive `param value`, and `$Params[1]` would receive `param 2 value`.

Note that when calling from *outside* of PowerShell:

- you *must not* use parameter name `-Params` in the invocation - just specify the *values* at the end.
- you *must not* use `,` to separate the values - use *spaces*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru, but this looks like it's related to "Partial Parameters" and "Parameter Completion".  [See this article for more information](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/04/22/the-problem-with-powershell-positional-parameters/).

Simply changing `Param` to `Param1` should fix the issue.

Comment: It might, but it shouldn't be because of partials. You need a partial parameter to be unambiguous.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give this article a read. Thanks for the reply

Comment: To rephrase @briantist's comment: Since `-Param` is an _exact_ match, there is no ambiguity, and PowerShell recognizes it - even if the parameter name happens to be a substring of another parameter name (even though that is a practice to be avoided).